# Отображение шрифта в разных браузерах

Tags: шрифты, css, браузер

В стилях указано `font-family: Courier, "Courier New", monospace;` В браузерах Google Chrome, IE8 и Opera 9.50 начертание шрифта отображается совершенно по-разному. Что не так и можно ли исправить?

Answer (score 1):

попробуй вот так

```
font: normal 12pt Courier, "Courier New", monospace;
```